# How to get text label with same button click c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i use picturebox to action click and my plan make 10 picturebox with same code but different get value example i use label to get text label.. how to get just one value if i make 10 label text and 10 picturebox with one action click.

```
  this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
  this.pictureBox2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
  this.pictureBox3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
  ......
  this.pictureBox10.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);


  private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //code ????
  }
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do change the label of the button?

Comment: `PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;` `pic.Name` is different

Comment: PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox) sender;
Then chech for pictureBox.Label

Comment: this my code is send to form2 text from label text from form 1.. i already success send text to form 2.. when i click button i get text from label to send to form 2.. example i used 10 button not picture box.. but on action all button all of code is a same.. just get text from label is different. so i just want make sort code with 1 button_click include all of button and get diffrent text from different label text without copy one by one button1_click till button10_click.. TQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control which raise the of Click event will be pass the the event handler function, and the first parameter **object sender** will be the control.

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

if pictureBox1 clicked, the parameter sender will be pictureBox1;
if pictureBox2 clicked, the parameter sender will be pictureBox1;

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    PictureBox pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    // Console.WriteLine(prictureBox.Name);
}
```

Comment: this my code is send to form2 text from label text from form 1.. i already success send text to form 2.. when i click button i get text from label to send to form 2.. example i used 10 button not picture box.. but on action all button all of code is a same.. just get text from label is different. so i just want make sort code with 1 button_click include all of button and get diffrent text from different label text without copy one by one button1_click till button10_click.. TQ

Comment: I tried to edit this one wrong number, but it wouldn't let me. Please fix. pictureBox2 -> pictureBox2